# How do you dump an IME's view Hierarchy?

Tags: android, android-layout, ddms, ime

I've just started developing an IME keyboard and am not able to use dump its view hierarchy for analysis. Every I use Android Device Monitor or DDMS to dump the view hierarchy while the keyboard is showing, I only get a dump of the activity in focus, even if it is part of the same APK and package.

How do I get the dump of the keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

The input method does not run in the activity window, it has a window of its own.

Select the `InputMethod` window in [`hierarchyviewer`](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-ui.html#HierarchyViewer).

Comment: How would I do this with the newer tools? HierarchyViewer is deprecated, and I also couldn't get it to connect to my rooted Nexus 4.

Comment: The Hierarchy Viewer in Eclipse has a Windows tab.